# ¿devolver mensaje de error con "Throw Exception" o "Return"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

Hola me surgió la duda de ¿que forma es más optima de retornar un mensaje en el caso que surja un error?
Throw Exception:

```
try
{
    .......
 return  cargarPersonas;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw  new Exception("Mensaje.", e);
}
```

Return:

```
try
{
    .......
 return  cargarPersonas;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return "Mensaje: " + e.message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Las 2 opciones tienen un fin diferente, la primera usando `throw` sirve para lanzar una excepción en nuestra aplicación.

```
try
{
    .......
 return  cargarPersonas;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    throw  new Exception("Mensaje.", e);
}
```

y la segunda opción retorna un String conteniendo el mensaje de error:

```
try
{
    .......
 return  cargarPersonas;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return "Mensaje: " + e.message;
}
```

Si lo que deseas es únicamente retornar un mensaje:

> ¿que forma es más optima de retornar un mensaje en el caso que surja
>   un error?

lo ideal sería la segunda opción.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [guía](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030(v=vs.110).aspx) de Microsoft, se dan las siguientes recomendaciones:

- Evitar devolver códigos de error
- Reportar errores **lanzando** excepciones.
- Si ocurre un error en el cual es peligroso seguir con la ejecución del programa, debe terminarse la ejecución.
- No usar excepciones para un control del flujo normal.
- Documentar las excepciones.
- No devolver excepciones de métodos
- Considerar usar `builders` para las excepciones.

Entre otras que pueden verse en la guía oficial.

Answer (score 0):

Claramente lanzar la excepción. Es decir, la primera opción.

El método que se encargue de recoger la excepción tendrá un objeto `Exception` completo con todas su propiedades incluyendo el mensaje descriptivo.

El método que recoja la excepción podrá controlarla o volver a lanzarla a un nivel superior si no puede manejarla.

Answer (score 0):

La primera opción es más acertada en caso de que necesites propagar el error a capas superiores, sin embargo no te recomiendo que crees un nuevo objeto Exception.

El inconveniente de la segunda opción es que solo puedes devolver un mesaje cuando tu método devuelva un string.

Lo que deberías hacer es:

Si anticipadamente sabes que bajo cierto estado, una operación puede fallar, es mejor que tu mismo lances la excepción:

`if(empleado == null || empleado.nombre == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Mensaje relacionado a objetos de empleados no inicializados");`

```
if(empleado.id < 0) throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Mensake de Id no válido: {0}", empleado.nombre));
```

lo que te permitirá tener un try/catch que unicamente progagará los errores:

```
try{ }catch{ throw; }
```

Que es básicamente lo mismo que:

```
try{ }catch(Exception exc) { throw exc; }
```

Lo que no deberías hacer es:

```
try{ }catch(Exception exc) { throw new Exception("Mensaje"); }
```

Ya que estarías sobreescribiendo información valiosa de la causa de la excepción y mandando únicamente un mensaje que seguramente será algo como: "falló la carga de usuarios" sin realmente tener información del tipo de excepción o un mensaje claro de la causa del error.